# Android Studio Error: "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method"

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been using Android Studio for a while now and it has never given me problems before this. I have tried everything from re-writing code to re-installing the software. I would greatly appreciate any help... Even this simple code does not work.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.ravinmadurawe.gpacalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.ravinmadurawe.gpacalculator.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="215dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ravinmadurawe.gpacalculator">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat

```
                                                                                   Process: com.example.ravinmadurawe.gpacalculator, PID: 5534
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ravinmadurawe.gpacalculator/com.example.ravinmadurawe.gpacalculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at com.example.ravinmadurawe.gpacalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: It will be better if you put a summary of the error in the beginning of the question. It makes me dizzy reading all your long code myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put `button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);` AFTER `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time off to help me!

Answer (score 1):

THIS LINE `button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);`should be under `setContentView`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time off to help me!